# Excel: WeekNum error in VBA and Formula Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

For each calendar the number of week of days 01-02-03/jan/2016 is 53th weeks.

But in excel(VBA and Sheet Formula) this is the week nr. 1 of 2016.

```
 cellValue = "01/01/2016"
 res = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(cellValue, 2)
```

This is serious mistake or correct ?

There is a patch for this problem ?

Comment: The weeknumber of the days 01-02-03/jan/2016 is not 53 in each calendar. There are different definitions of week numbering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using 21 and not 2 as the second argument.

Comment: don't run correctly with 21 as second parameter, is equals to 1,2...21

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have? It returns 53 using your code with 21 instead of 2 in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using the ISO definition of week number. If so then you'll need to change the line to:

```
res = DatePart("ww", d, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

For a really good explanation of VBA for weeknum calculations, have a look at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WeekNumbers.aspx.

BTW, the function `=WEEKNUM()` and `WorksheetFunction.Weeknum()` work differently in the Excel versions, so you might have more control with a pure VBA solution.